# Shortest way to run seven if statements in Python

Tags: python

I have an `if` statements that checks a number and then return a string value accordingly.

**code:**

```
def get_weekday(day):
    if day in ['1', 1]:
        return 'Monday'
    elif day in ['2', 2]:
        return 'Tuesday'
    elif day in ['3', 3]:
        return 'Wednesday'
    elif day in ['4', 4]:
        return 'Thursday'
    elif day in ['5', 5]:
        return 'Friday'
    elif day in ['6', 6]:
        return 'Saturday'
    elif day in ['7', 7]:
        return 'Sunday'
    return 'Invalid day selected'
```

The question may appear subjective but I think there should be a **pythonic** and better and shorter and cleaner way of writing this.

Comment: Why are you using in? How do you have ints and strings?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `day` is coming from Django from from the template.

Comment: @Yax, so django returns different types?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on my answer @Yax. I adjusted it and provided an updated output per the spec on your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do instead, is create a dictionary, and cast your `day` to a single type, and then look that up in your dictionary. This significantly minimizes your code:

```
def get_weekday(day):
    days_dict = {
        '1': 'Monday',
        '2': 'Tuesday',
        '3': 'Wednesday',
        '4': 'Thursday',
        '5': 'Friday',
        '6': 'Saturday',
        '7': 'Sunday'
    }
    return days_dict.get(str(day), 'Invalid day selected')
```

So, what is happening in the above function, is you are passing your `day`, it doesn't matter whether you pass it as a string or an int, the casting is made as an `str` already. Your dictionary now holds the mapping for you, and lookup will cost you O(1).

The `get` method will return `None` if it does not find an entry in your dictionary. However, per your requirement, you are looking to return `Invalid day selected` for invalid entries. `get` will take an extra argument that will be returned in the event an invalid key is provided.

Here is a demo of the different cases that can come up and how the function behaves:

```
>>> print(get_weekday(2))
Tuesday
>>> print(get_weekday('5'))
Friday
>>> print(get_weekday("invalid_thing"))
Invalid day selected
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)** aka map and simply put in multiple keys for the same values.

Then you only need to ask that dictionary for the value matching the current *day* key.

Comment: Any comments by the brave anonymous downvoter on whats wrong with that answer?

Comment: They probably downvoted you because you didn't provide any code example.

Comment: Which is a stupid reason to downvote. The explanation is clearly there.

Comment: Maybe. And obviously the other answers are better. But thanks for you two folks to give a reply.

Comment: The only thing I probably would have added to your solution if you were going the "hint" route, is to provide the link to the dictionary doc. Cheers.

Comment: Which I did. Well, just now. Lets see if that makes a difference ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution would be:

```
def get_day_name(day):
    return {
        '1': 'Monday',
        '2': 'Tuesday',
        '3': 'Wednesday',
        '4': 'Thursday',
        '5': 'Friday',
        '6': 'Saturday',
        '7': 'Sunday'
    }.get(str(day), 'Invalid day selected')
```

Several things are done here:

1. to get rid of checking both strings `'2'` and integers `2`, convert all to strings: `str(day)`
2. there is a mapping (`dict`) from all allowed strings (`'1'` - `'7'`) to the results
3. instead of just taking the result with `{...}[day]`, dictionary provides methog `get` which accepts the *default* argument to be returned if the key is not found (`'Invalid day selected'`).

---

But then again, since those are just numbers, this can be simplified using a list instead of a dictionary:

```
def get_day_name(day):
    day = int(day)
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

    if 1 <= day <= 7:
        return days[day-1]
    else:
        return 'Invalid day selected'
```

In this case, strings are first converted to integers and then the integers are used to get a value from the list.
This, of course, won't work if `day = 'something that isnt int'`. This would raise an exception which could be handled, but if that has to be handled, the solution with dict is nicer.

Comment: The code example is good, but please provide a description about what it's doing.

Comment: `days[7] -> IndexError` `days[1] -> Tuesday`

Comment: @Soviut Yes, it felt like it needed more text as soon as I wrote it ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary. The `get` method of the dictionary returns the default `'Invalid day selected'` when the given `day` is not in the dictionary:

```
days_in_week = {1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday', 7: 'Sunday'}

def func(day):
    return days_in_week.get(int(day), 'Invalid day selected')
```

The cast to integer using `int` allows the function to take both strings and integer `day` parameter.